# unable to get log4net working with .net windows service

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a windows service with an `app.config` and a `log4net.config`.

`app.config`:

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net configSource="log4net.config" />
```

`log4net.config`:

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:\Projects\Integration\Interface Module\bin\Logs\MyFirstLogger.log"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I have added this in `AssemblyInfo.cs` too:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And in one of my classes, I have:

```
private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and

```
_log.Info(content);
```

I have given **all** users full permissions to my Logs folder.

My bin folder (which the service is running from) has both my `app.config` and `log4net.config`.

But no logging file got generated. What settings did I miss?

**Updated on 4-March-2014**

If you are using a separate config file like I did (log4net.config), do remember to set the `Copy to output directory` setting to `Copy always` in the Solution Explorer

Comment: Is this running in an IIS app? You'll need to give IIS_IUSRS full permissions to the log dir if so.

Comment: It's hosted as a windows service

Comment: You mention giving user permission to your log folder, but is your service actually running as a user (as opposed to something like LocalService) ?

Comment: Is the attribute `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` and the call to `LogManager.GetLogger` in the same assembly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By Design Log4Net is

> **fail-stop,** we mean that log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions
>   at run-time potentially causing your application to crash

So it is very difficult to figure out what is causing the issue .

> How do I enable log4net internal debugging?

FROM FAQ - http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html

- Internal debugging can also be enabled by setting a value in the
  application's configuration file (not the log4net configuration file,
  unless the log4net config data is embedded in the application's
  config file). The log4net.Internal.Debug application setting must be
  set to the value true. For example:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
> <configuration>
>             <appSettings>
>                 <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
>             </appSettings> 
> </configuration>
> ```

This setting is read immediately on startup an will cause all internal debugging messages to be emitted.

- . To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set
     the **log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging** property to true.
     Obviously the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced.

> So here is a custom class i created for log4Net - because config file
>   was very confusing   I created this helper class

- you can initiate as many appender you need across the applications
     so if one dll call other dll both can initiate appenders and both
     appends will work.
- also you can close the appender and ( as in case of file appender)
     then send it as a email

> ```
> Log4NetFileHelper log = new Log4NetFileHelper();
>         log.Init(); //Initialize
>         log.AddConsoleLogging(); //Add Console Logging
>         log.AddFileLogging(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, "BatchConsole.log")); 
>         log.AddFileLogging(Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory,"BatchConsole_error.log"),log4net.Core.Level.Error);
> ```
>
> Do set this Property to True  log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging=true;

```
public class Log4NetFileHelper
{
    private string  DEFAULT_LOG_FILENAME=string.Format("application_log_{0}.log",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMMdd_hhmm"));
    Logger root;
    public Log4NetFileHelper()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Init()
    {
        root = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
        //root.AddAppender(GetConsoleAppender());
        //root.AddAppender(GetFileAppender(sFileName));
        root.Repository.Configured = true;
    }

    #region Public Helper Methods
    #region Console Logging
    public virtual void AddConsoleLogging()
    {
        ConsoleAppender C = GetConsoleAppender();
        AddConsoleLogging(C);
    }

    public virtual void AddConsoleLogging(ConsoleAppender C)
    {
        root.AddAppender(C);
    }
    #endregion

    #region File Logging
    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging()
    {
        return AddFileLogging(DEFAULT_LOG_FILENAME);
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath)
    {
        return AddFileLogging(sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level.All);
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level threshold)
    {
        return AddFileLogging(sFileFullPath, threshold,true);  
    }

    public virtual FileAppender AddFileLogging(string sFileFullPath, log4net.Core.Level threshold, bool bAppendfile)
    {
        FileAppender appender = GetFileAppender(sFileFullPath, threshold , bAppendfile);
        root.AddAppender(appender);
        return appender;
    }

    public virtual SmtpAppender AddSMTPLogging(string smtpHost, string From, string To, string CC, string subject, log4net.Core.Level threshhold)
    {
        SmtpAppender appender = GetSMTPAppender(smtpHost, From, To, CC, subject, threshhold);
         root.AddAppender(appender);
         return appender;
    }

    #endregion


    public log4net.Appender.IAppender GetLogAppender(string AppenderName)
    {
        AppenderCollection ac = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Appenders;

        foreach(log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in ac){
            if (appender.Name == AppenderName)
            {
                return appender;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void CloseAppender(string AppenderName)
    {
        log4net.Appender.IAppender appender = GetLogAppender(AppenderName);
        CloseAppender(appender);
    }

    private void CloseAppender(log4net.Appender.IAppender appender)
    {
        appender.Close();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private SmtpAppender GetSMTPAppender(string smtpHost, string From, string To, string CC, string subject, log4net.Core.Level threshhold)
    {
        SmtpAppender lAppender = new SmtpAppender();
        lAppender.Cc = CC;
        lAppender.To = To;
        lAppender.From = From;
        lAppender.SmtpHost = smtpHost;
        lAppender.Subject = subject;
        lAppender.BufferSize = 512;
        lAppender.Lossy = false;
        lAppender.Layout = new
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
        lAppender.Threshold = threshhold;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    }

    private ConsoleAppender GetConsoleAppender()
    {
        ConsoleAppender lAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        lAppender.Name = "Console";
        lAppender.Layout = new 
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout(" %message %n");
        lAppender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.All;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    } 
    /// <summary>
    /// DETAILED Logging 
    /// log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
    ///  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <param name="threshhold"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private FileAppender GetFileAppender(string sFileName , log4net.Core.Level threshhold ,bool bFileAppend)
    {
        FileAppender lAppender = new FileAppender();
        lAppender.Name = sFileName;
        lAppender.AppendToFile = bFileAppend;
        lAppender.File = sFileName;
        lAppender.Layout = new 
        log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %5level [%2thread] %message (%logger{1}:%line)%n");
        lAppender.Threshold = threshhold;
        lAppender.ActivateOptions();
        return lAppender;
    }

    //private FileAppender GetFileAppender(string sFileName)
    //{
    //    return GetFileAppender(sFileName, log4net.Core.Level.All,true);
    //}

    #endregion

    private void  ConfigureLog(string sFileName)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Please note that when the process is run as Windows Service, Environment.CurrentDirectory will be "C:\Windows\system32"

So if you put the log4net configuration file (log4net.config) next to your *.exe, you can use the following code to configure log4net.

```
var assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "log4net.config")));
```

Comment: This was it for me.  Also note that for the same reason you probably don't want to use relative paths in your logging file names, as they'll end up under windows\system32, if permissions even allow writing at all.

Comment: Good answer. Worked for me too.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the config that works for me.

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**Log4net.Config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
            <param name="File" value="C:\TEMP\Logs.txt"/>
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock,log4net" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
         <level value="ALL" />
         <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

**C# Code**

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(class_name));
```

I have this setup in C# Class library project and all other project uses this project reference to log the exceptions.

Comment: in my case issue appeared to be with FileAppender.  I've replaced it RollingFileAppender and it worked fine.  Nothing helped before.

Comment: Only y change GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); and work perfect thanks man!

Answer (score 9):

After checking and recheck... :-)

All you need is to call `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` before you create the logger (only once).

Glad to help you,

Ofir

Comment: I did it in my AssemblyInfo.cs [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

Comment: I think you either need to call XmlConfigurator.Configure() or else change your assemblyInfo.cs to use [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true, ConfigFile="log4net.config")]

Comment: It does not work for me in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  Please call 'XmlConfigurator.Configure();' before 'GetLogger'.  Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

If you will make a different configuration file and put log4net related things in it, then you will need to use 
`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"...\log4net.config", Watch = true)]`
inside *AssemblyInfo.cs* instead of just

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

Otherwise, you have to put 
`<log4net>
...
</log4net>` part of the configuration inside your *App.config*

Comment: ConfigFile = @"...\log4net.config" <- this must be the full directory? Or do I just put exactly "...\log4net.config"

Comment: It must be the full path of the log4net.config. if it is located in your `C:\temp` for example, you should enter `C:\temp\log4net.config` I am not sure it accepts relative paths, it worths giving it a try

Comment: [This](http://juststuffreally.blogspot.com/2008/11/log4net-using-named-config-file.html) article explains the usage clearly. I hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if some of these seem obvious, but these are what I would check:

- Make sure you have your log4net.config file properties Copy to Output set to Copy Always, verify by checking for the file in your bin directory
- Also note from the log4net docs related to AssemblyInfo.cs properties:

> *Using attributes can be a clearer method for defining where the application's configuration will be loaded from. However it is worth
>   noting that attributes are purely passive. They are information only.
>   Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a
>   logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and
>   invoked**.*

- To troubleshoot you might try switching from the assembly level property to an explicit configuration call

  XmlConfigurator.Configure();

  should be sufficient.
- I always make log4net.config a full config file, starting with

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" 
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
  ...
    </log4net>
  </configuration>
  ```

You should not need anything in app.config related to log4net as long as your config file is log4net.config

Comment: `it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up` This made me waste an entire day of work looking for bugs in two _identically configured_ projects, one working and one not

Answer (score 3):

When you say 'All Users' have full permissions to the log directory, does this include the service accounts?

Check that LocalService, NetworkService, LocalSystem etc have permissions (depending on what context the service is running).

Also, assuming you have a harness to run the service as an application, does logging work when running as your user?

If it doesn't run okay as an application, you've got a problem with the log4net config (which other answers have tried to address).

Answer (score 1):

log4net runs under the privileges of the active user. Make sure that the active user has rights to create/modify/delete the specified text file.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please upload you application so that i could debug it myself?

a few i recommend to check:

1. replace all the "\" in your file path to "\"
2. put all the log4net config embedded in the application's config file.
3. enable log4net debugging
   ([see here](http://www.haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx))
4. try a different configuration. just get a sample config for somewhere on the internet.
5. just to be sure, i'd give maximum permissions for all users to your logging directory
6. try to uninstall the service and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation of comment from Yanting Chen in above thread -
With below code, you can find what all config messages are logged by log4net when running the app under Windows Scheduler. It may help someone to get insight of log4net especially when running under services or scheduler where you can't see the command screen.

```
  private static void InstanceLogger()
    {
        if (logger == null)
            logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Utility));

        // Code to troubleshoot Log4Net issues through Event log viewer
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (log4net.Util.LogLog m in logger.Logger.Repository.ConfigurationMessages)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(m.Message);
        }

        throw new Exception("String messages: " + sb.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a separate file for log4net.config. Have you set following property:

Copy to the output directory = Copy always

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code has a minor issue in AssemblyInfo.cs.

replace your code by :
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "{{folder_path}}\log4net.config")]

where {{folder_path}} is the path of your log4net.config

Answer (score 0):

Windows Service with system login does not have access to all the directories present.
So try logging in the "C:\Users\Public\AppData".
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Running [`Dbgview.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) from Microsoft SysinternalsSuite as admin --> Capture Global Win32 --> start your service, showed me that my `log4net.config` was simply not in the same directory as the windows service executable.  Left click `log4net.config` in VS and in Properties --> Advanced --> set Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer.  That way Build will include the file in bin as it necessary to run the service.

- See `How do I enable log4net internal debugging?` from [log4net's
  FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html).
- I followed this [tutorial](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) to add logging to my service.