# Log4Net creating empty Log file

Tags: c#, log4net, nuget-package, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Hi I am trying to write my console output to a log file and i only see it created a log file but it is not writing anything into the log file.

Please find the below attached App.config and AssemblyInfo.cs filesand also the changes i have done to my code.

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
      <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="D:\Logs\abc.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <levelMin value="INFO" />
          <levelMax value="ERROR" />
        </filter>
      </appender>
      

  </log4net>
    </configuration>
```

Assemblyinfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


//Log4Net Configurations

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

C# Console App Code:

```
 class Program
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(LogPath)) 
                {
                    log.Info("Log Directory Exists, Starting execution");
                    Console.WriteLine(LogPath, "Directory Exists {0}");
                    log.Debug("Checking for Log Directory, It Exists !!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(LogPath, "Doesn't Exists, Creating the Folder");
                    DirectoryInfo LogPathfolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath);
                    log.Info("Creating LogPath Folder");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                log.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

New App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\abc\abc.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-3level %logger : %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Are you using .NET or .NET Framework? Which version?

Comment: You may be able to extract some code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806343/10024425) (it's VB.NET).

Comment: On the root configuration node you could only set a single level node (if you specify info level it includes warning, errors and critical ecc.). Try also to remove the filter on the appender and simplify the configuration file in general.

Comment: I have done the above mentioned changes in my app.config file but i am still getting empty log file.