# VB.NET and DataGridView: how read a specific Cell value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview, basic, selectedvalue

I have a DataGridView of 3 columns and 3 rows (it's just an example). I would like to read only the value of a specific cell (in this example 2x2). How do you do this? I try this code but visual studio write me there is an error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information:

> Index non compreso nell'intervallo. Richiesto valore non negativo e minore della dimensione della raccolta."

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'read array and send to DataGridView

    Dim cella(3, 3) As String

    cella(0, 0) = "Papa"
    cella(0, 1) = "Mamma"
    cella(0, 2) = "Bimbo1"
    cella(0, 3) = "Bimbo2"

    cella(1, 0) = "Bianco"
    cella(1, 1) = "Rosso"
    cella(1, 2) = "Nero"
    cella(1, 3) = "Blu"

    cella(2, 0) = "Firenze"
    cella(2, 1) = "Pisa"
    cella(2, 2) = "Livorno"
    cella(2, 3) = "Empoli"

    cella(3, 0) = "Gatto"
    cella(3, 1) = "Cane"
    cella(3, 2) = "Panda"
    cella(3, 3) = "Macaco"

    For x As Integer = 0 To 3
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("newColumnName", "Testo")
    Next

    For y As Integer = 0 To cella.GetUpperBound(0)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cella(0, y), cella(1, y), cella(2, y), cella(3, y))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    
    'Create MsgBox with the value of the specified cell 
    MsgBox(DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(2).Cells(2).Value.ToString())

End Sub
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806343/10024425

Comment: You need to read the relevant documentation. The SelectedRows property contains the rows that are selected. Are there any rows selected? Presumably not, so obviously any index will be out of range. If you want a specific row, get it from the Rows collection.

Comment: The MsgBox should show me the string "Livorno" without the user having to select it.. How can I do?

Comment: You do it as I already told you how to do it. Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: You don't even need to get the row first and then the cell from that. You can get the cell directly from the grid. Index the grid itself using column index and row index and that will give you the cell at those coordinates. Again, the documentation would tell you that. You should always be reading the relevant documentation before posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the data in the UI. UI is for display and interaction, not for storing state.

Create a class to represent your data

```vb
Private Class Datum
    Public Sub New(name As String, color As String, city As String, animal As String)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Color = color
        Me.City = city
        Me.Animal = animal
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Color As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property Animal As String
End Class
```

then populate the list with instances of the class and bind the data to the DataGridView

```vb
Private data As List(Of Datum)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    data = New List(Of Datum) From
        {
            New Datum("Papa", "Bianco", "Firenze", "Gatto"),
            New Datum("Mamma", "Rosso", "Pisa", "Cane"),
            New Datum("Bimbo1", "Nero", "Livorno", "Panda"),
            New Datum("Bimbo2", "Blu", "Empoli", "Macaco")
        }
    DataGridView1.DataSource = data
End Sub
```

and finally find the item you are looking for using some logic

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim city = data?.Single(Function(d) d.Name = "Bimbo1").City
    MessageBox.Show(city)
End Sub
```

[image]

Now your data is off the UI, and you can access it using logical names, pass the data around, query it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception occur because you have no SelectedRows. If you want only a fix cell try `Row` insteed of `SelectedRows`:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click    
  'Create MsgBox with the value of the specified cell 
  MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows.Item(2).Cells(2).Value.ToString())
End Sub
```